# Sending Raw Data to USB Dot Matrix Printer using C#

Tags: c#, printing, usb

I am working on a simple application that will be reading a text file that will overwritten every 5 minutes with some telemetry data.

I was trying to use microsoft PrintDocument but it wont work for this case because i need to have control of the printer spooler to print a new line every five but in the same page than the previous (continously). This is not possible with PrintDocument class at least for my understanding, because you cannot have control of the spooler with this class and each print command its a job and when it finishes the job then the printer scrolls the page to taken by the user. If someone knows if there is a way to continue printing in the same page every 5 minutes please share the information or example.

I am using an Okidata Microline 186 USB dot matrix printer and after a few tries with other third parties libraries with out any luck i found RawPrintHelper.cs class and i am trying it and i were able to send RAW data to the printer with this class but i have some issues. The class is here:

This is the original class code:

public class RawPrinterHelper
{
  // Struct

```
ure and API declarions:
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
  public class DOCINFOA
  {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
  }
  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="OpenPrinterA", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="ClosePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool StartDocPrinter( IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level,  [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="EndDocPrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="StartPagePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="EndPagePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

  [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="WritePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten );

  // SendBytesToPrinter()
  // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
  // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
  // Returns true on success, false on failure.
  public static bool SendBytesToPrinter( string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
  {
    Int32    dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
    IntPtr    hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
    DOCINFOA    di = new DOCINFOA();
    bool    bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
    di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
    di.pDataType = "RAW";

    // Open the printer.
    if( OpenPrinter( szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero ) )
    {
      // Start a document.
      if( StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) )
      {
        // Start a page.
        if( StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) )
        {
          // Write your bytes.
          bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
          EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
      }
      ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    }
    // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
    // about why not.
    if( bSuccess == false )
    {
      dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }
    return bSuccess;
  }

  public static bool SendFileToPrinter( string szPrinterName, string szFileName )
  {
    // Open the file.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
    // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
    Byte []bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
    bool bSuccess = false;
    // Your unmanaged pointer.
    IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
    int nLength;

    nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
    // Read the contents of the file into the array.
    bytes = br.ReadBytes( nLength );
    // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
    pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
    // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
    // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
    bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
    // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
    return bSuccess;
  }

  public static bool SendStringToPrinter( string szPrinterName, string szString )
  {
    IntPtr pBytes;
    Int32 dwCount;

    // How many characters are in the string?
    // Fix from Nicholas Piasecki:
    // dwCount = szString.Length;
    dwCount = (szString.Length + 1) * Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize;

    // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
    // the string to ANSI text.
    pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
    // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
    SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
    return true;
  }
}

 public partial class USB : Form
{
    public USB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;

        // How many characters are in the string?
        // Fix from Nicholas Piasecki:
        // dwCount = szString.Length;
        dwCount = (szString.Length + 1) * Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize;

        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }     


    private void buttonSEND_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog open = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        string dados = "";
        if (open.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(open.FileName);
            dados = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
        string printer = "PRINTER NAME";

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            SendStringToPrinter(printer, dados);    
        }

    }
}

Issues:
First problem was that it prints only using a file with this method "SendFileToPrinter":

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);


   // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
    return bSuccess;
}
```

However it dont work perfectly, the printer head stay to the right side of the page and when it try to print again then it writes the beginning of the text at the right of the page and then continue with the rest of the text. The second option that is using this method which receives an string to print:

```
public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
{
    IntPtr pBytes;
    Int32 dwCount;

    // How many characters are in the string?
    // Fix from Nicholas Piasecki:
    // dwCount = szString.Length;
    dwCount = (szString.Length + 1) * Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize;

    // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
    // the string to ANSI text.
    pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
    // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
    SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
    return true;
}
```

But this method is no sending anything to the printer, The printer dont begin print. I made a hybrid from both functions by taking a look at both methods and i finally able to print with this code but with same alignment issues as with the SendFileToPrinter, no mater if i send the text always in the same format delimited by tabs each line that i send to the printer is not well aligned.

This is my piece of code:

```
        public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        bool bSuccess = false;
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(szString).Length;
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[nLength];
        bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(szString);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }
```

This is an example of what i need to print:

[Expected Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3yEx.png)

The first tree lines are for the header of the table. and the next lines will be printed one of them each 5 minutes with readings of values.

How ever its not consistent even after formatted the string and delimited by tabs.

This is what i am getting when  print with my Frankenstein method.

PAGE TITLE                                                      ........ LINE 1
VAL3        VAL4                                       VAL1       VAL2
                                                       Time / Date         DESC       DESC        DESC        DESC    ........ LINE 3
                                       3/4/2019 11:30 AM   100        300         500         434      ........ LINE 4
                         3/4/2019 11:35 AM   99         290         340         452      ........ LINE 5
3/4/2019 11:40 AM   120        310         100         532      ........ LINE 6

Its not consistent  and only the first line prints ok and aligned. I am newbie in this of sending raw data to the printer and i dont whats going on that is causing this when i call the method SendStringToPrinter(myString) every five minutes. I dont know if i need to specify the coordinates or where to start printing neither how to do it.

I will appreciate any help in order to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question, yes WritePrinter is the way to go because that allows you to send raw bytes. I'm not reading into the details of all your code because that is way too much code for this question.

For the layout part of this question, that printer looks like it is expecting ESC/POS. Here is the [command sheet](https://okiprinting-en-us.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/970/~/commands---microline-standard-commands-for-the-ml184-turbo-and-ml186). Update your text file to conform to those commands, namely the page format section. e.g.

```
ESC HT 12 Hello 08 World
```

would align "World" to the 8th character position. You'll need to experiment with the commands to find what works. If you're new to ESC/POS I would recommend using notepad++ to create your test files. If you enable the character panel (Edit->Character Panel) you can inject arbitrary ASCII codes into the file. An ESC/POS string of the above would be:

```
1b090cHello09World
```